# ImageView in custom row for List is out of alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom row for a list. I want to place an image of arrow as a visual guide for the user to tap.

The image starts on a new row and never lines up correctly on the right edge of the cell.

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtYMMC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Year Make Model Color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCallNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call Number: 0000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisclosureArrow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowright" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here it a picture of what is happening

[image]

Here is what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Year Make Model Color"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Call Number: 0000"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/arrowright"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Some of the attributes that you used (for example `android:layout_alignParentRight`) are not used in a LinearLayout...

Of course there are other ways too, but this is just one way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` orientation is **vertical**, change it to **horizontal** that is why `ImageView` its shown bellow other elements. Try this

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0p"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Year Make Model Color"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Call Number: 0000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrowright"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!!